# Display png image where desktop wallpaper shows through image transparency

Tags: image-viewer

I'm running the latest version of Openbox & Arch.
Everything on my system was updated last week.

How can I display a png image with background transparency on the desktop so that the desktop wallpaper shows through the image transparency, without any surrounding border or frame, positioned at the bottom centre of the screen.

Did quite a few searches and came up with nothing.

Is there a tool that will do this.

So far I only found the **qiv** utility, but the '-i' or '--no_statusbar' flag does not work.

```
qiv --no_statusbar -p my_file.png
```

In essence what I want to do is display an image file, like you see when you press for example caps lock, and an A or a flashes up for a moment to show you where you are.

I do not think **yad** can do it, and I find **dunst** too unreliable and resource heavy.

Comment: I've never seen this caps lock image you refer to, but it sounds like a good idea for a lot of users! Nice. Anyway, do you perchance know which program / session manager service displays that overlay? Because maybe you can just send a message to that saying "hey, display this image"

Comment: Thanks, it's not a caps lock image, it's the principle of being able to do this. It is to display any small image, small in geometry and small in file size.

Comment: yes, I understand that. The question was whether you happen to know which program does that for you, as that same program might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: If i knew that i wouldn't be on here